# Variance of Cohen's $d$ statistic

Tags: variance, effect-size, cohens-d

Cohen’s $d$ is one of the most common ways we measure the size of an effect ([see Wikipedia](http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_d)). It simply measures the distance between two means in terms of the pooled standard deviation. How can we derive the mathematical formula of variance estimate of Cohen's $d$?

**December 2015 edit:** Related to this question is the idea of [calculating confidence intervals](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184869/effect-size-pdf-and-confidence-intervals) around $d$. [This article](http://www.leeds.ac.uk/educol/documents/00002182.htm) states that

$$\sigma_{d}^2 = \dfrac{n_{+}}{n_{\times}} + \dfrac{d^2}{2n_{+}} $$

where $n_{+}$ is the sum of the two sample sizes and $n_{\times}$ is the product of the two sample sizes.

**How is this formula derived?**

Comment: @Clarinetist: It is somewhat controversial to edit another person's question to *add more substance and more questions to it* (as opposed to improving the wording). I took the liberty to approve your edit (given that you placed a generous bounty and that I think your edit does improve the question), but others might decide to roll back.

Comment: @amoeba No problem. As long as the formula is there for $\sigma^2_d$ (which wasn't there before) and it's clear that we're looking for a mathematical derivation of the formula, that's fine.

Comment: I think the denominator of the second fraction should be $2(n_{+}-2)$.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Note that the variance expression in the question is an approximation.  [Hedges (1981)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1164588) derived the large sample variance of $d$ and approximation in a general setting (i.e. multiple experiments/studies), and my answer pretty much walks through the derivations in the paper.

First, the assumptions we'll utilize are the following:

Let's assume we have two independent treatment groups, $T$ (treatment) and $C$ (control). Let $Y_{Ti}$ and $Y_{Cj}$ be the scores/responses/whatever from subject $i$ in group $T$ and subject $j$ in group $C$, respectively.

We assume the responses are normally distributed and the treatment and control groups share a common variance, i.e.

\begin{align*}
Y_{Ti} &\sim N(\mu_T, \sigma^2), \quad i = 1, \dots n_T \\
Y_{Cj} &\sim N(\mu_C, \sigma^2), \quad j = 1, \dots n_C
\end{align*}

The effect size we're interested in estimating in each study is $\delta = \frac{\mu_T - \mu_C}{\sigma}$.  The estimator of the effect size we'll use is
\begin{equation*}
d = \frac{\bar{Y}_T - \bar{Y}_C}{\sqrt{\frac{(n_T - 1)S_T^2 + (n_C - 1)S_C^2}{n_T + n_C - 2}}}
\end{equation*}
where $S_k^2$ is the unbiased sample variance for group $k$.

Let's consider the large-sample properties of $d$.

First, note that:
\begin{equation*}
\bar{Y}_T - \bar{Y}_C \sim N \Bigg( \mu_T - \mu_C, \,\sigma^2\frac{n_T + n_C}{n_T n_C} \Bigg)
\end{equation*} 
and (being loose with my notation):
\begin{equation}
\frac{(n_T - 1)S_T^{2}}{\sigma^2(n_T + n_C - 2)} = \frac{1}{n_T + n_C - 2}\frac{(n_T - 1)S_T^{2}}{\sigma^2} \sim \frac{1}{n_T + n_C- 2}\chi_{n_T - 1}^2 \tag{1}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\frac{(n_C - 1)S_C^{2}}{\sigma^2(n_T + n_C - 2)} = \frac{1}{n_T + n_C - 2}\frac{(n_C - 1)S_C^{2}}{\sigma^2} \sim \frac{1}{n_T + n_C- 2}\chi_{n_C - 1}^2 \tag{2}
\end{equation}

Equations (1) and (2) lead to the fact that (again, being loose with my notation):
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\frac{(n_T - 1)S_T^{2} + (n_C - 1)S_C^{2}}{n_T + n_C - 2} \sim \frac{1}{n_T + n_C - 2}\chi_{n_T + n_C - 2}^2
\end{equation*}

Now, some clever algebra:
\begin{align*}
d &= \frac{\bar{Y}_T - \bar{Y}_C}{\sqrt{\frac{(n_T - 1)S_T^2 + (n_C - 1)S_C^2}{n_T + n_C - 2}}} \\\\
&= \frac{\left(\sigma\sqrt{\frac{n_T + n_C}{n_T n_C}}\right)^{-1}(\bar{Y}_T - \bar{Y}_C)}{\left(\sigma\sqrt{\frac{n_T + n_C}{n_T n_C}}\right)^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{(n_T - 1)S_T^2 + (n_C - 1)S_C^2}{n_T + n_C - 2}}} \\\\
&= \frac{\frac{(\bar{Y}_T - \bar{Y}_C) - (\mu_T - \mu_C)}{\sigma\sqrt{\frac{n_T + n_C}{n_T n_C}}} + \frac{\mu_T - \mu_C}{\sigma\sqrt{\frac{n_T + n_C}{n_T n_C}}}}{\left(\sqrt{\frac{n_T + n_C}{n_T n_C}}\right)^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{(n_T - 1)S_T^2 + (n_C - 1)S_C^2}{\sigma^2(n_T + n_C - 2)}}} \\\\
&= \sqrt{\frac{n_T + n_C}{n_T n_C}}\left(\frac{\theta + \delta\sqrt{\frac{n_T n_C}{n_T + n_C}}}{\sqrt{\frac{V}{\nu}}}\right)
\end{align*}
where $\theta \sim N(0,1)$, $V \sim \chi^2_{\nu}$, and $\nu = n_T+n_C-2$. Thus, $d$ is $\sqrt{\frac{n_T + n_C}{n_T n_C}}$ times a variable which follows a non-central t-distribution with $n_T + n_C - 2$ degrees of freedom and non-centrality parameter of $\delta\sqrt{\frac{n_T n_C}{n_T + n_C}}$.

Using the [moment properties of the non-central $t$ distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_t-distribution#Moments_of_the_Noncentral_t-distribution), it follows that:
\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{Var}(d) = \frac{(n_T + n_C - 2)}{(n_T + n_C - 4)}\frac{(n_T + n_C)}{n_T n_C}(1+ \delta^2\frac{n_T n_C}{n_T + n_C}) - \frac{\delta^2}{b^2} \tag{3}
\end{equation*}
where 
\begin{equation*}
b = \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n_T + n_C - 2}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\frac{n_T+n_C-2}{2}}\Gamma\left(\frac{n_T+n_C-3}{2}\right)} \approx 1 - \frac{3}{4(n_T+n_C-2)-1}
\end{equation*}

So Equation (3) provides the exact large sample variance.  Note that an unbiased estimator for $\delta$ is $b d$, with variance:

\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{Var}(bd) = b^2\frac{(n_T + n_C - 2)}{(n_T + n_C - 4)}\frac{(n_T + n_C)}{n_T n_C}(1+ \delta^2\frac{n_T n_C}{n_T + n_C}) - \delta^2 
\end{equation*}

For large degrees of freedom (i.e. large $n_T+n_C-2$), the variance of a non-central $t$ variate with $\nu$ degrees of freedom and non-centrality parameter $p$ can be approximated by $1 + \frac{p^2}{2\nu}$ ([Johnson, Kotz, Balakrishnan, 1995](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471584940.html)).  Thus, we have:
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Var}(d) &\approx \frac{n_T + n_C}{n_T n_C}\left(1 + \frac{\delta^2\left(\frac{n_T n_C}{n_T + n_C}\right)}{2(n_T+n_C-2)}\right)
 \\\\
&= \frac{n_T + n_C}{n_T n_C} + \frac{\delta^2}{2(n_T+n_C-2)}
\end{align*}

Plug in our estimator for $\delta$ and we're done.

Comment: Very, very nice derivation. Just a few questions: 1) could you clarify what the notation $\bar{Y}^{T}_{i} - \bar{Y}^{C}_{i}$ means (I know it's something to do with difference of sample means, but how can they both have the same index?)? 2) could you clarify how the approximation for $b$ is done (I don't need all of the details, a source is fine and maybe a brief explanation)? Otherwise, I'm quite pleased with this. (+1) This also agrees with the observation that I've made that $d$ doesn't follow a normal distribution, contrary to the explanation in the linked article in the OP.

Comment: @Clarinetist Thanks!
1) How can they have the same index?  Typo, that's how! :P  They're an artifact of my first draft of the answer.  I'll fix that.
2) I pulled it from the Hedges paper -- don't know its derivation at the moment but will think about it some more.

Comment: I'm looking into the derivation now, but FYI, the numerator of $b$ should be $\Gamma\left(\dfrac{n_T+n_C-2}{2}\right)$.

Comment: Derivation provided for reference: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1564587/frac-gamma-fracn-t-n-c-22-sqrt-fracn-tn-c-22-gamma-left-f . Turns out there's likely a sign error.

Comment: @mike : very impressing answer. Thanks for taking the time to share it with us.

Comment: @Clarinetist yep, you're correct - fixed.  And thanks, Denis!