# Bayes factor for effect size

Tags: bayesian, effect-size, model-comparison, cohens-d, bayes-factors

I need to construct Bayes Factor for testing: 
$$ H_0: \quad 0 = \mu_t - \mu_c $$ 
$$ H_1: \quad 0 \neq \mu_t - \mu_c $$
and my prior knowledge is modeled by distribution of effect size: $ \delta = \frac{\mu_t - \mu_c}{\sigma} \backsim N(\lambda, \sigma_{\delta})$

I've based on this properties of Cohen's effect size: [enter link description here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144084/variance-of-cohens-d-statistic)
So:
$$ BF =  \frac{\frac{\theta}{\sqrt{V/v}}}{\frac{\theta + \sigma}{\sqrt{V/v}}}$$ 
and I get:
$$ BF = \frac{T_v(t|0,1)}{T_v(t|\lambda n_{\delta}^{1/2}, n_{\delta}\sigma_{\delta})} $$
because $\theta + \sigma \backsim N(\lambda n_{\delta}^{1/2}, n_{\delta}\sigma_{\delta})$ and $n_{\delta} = \frac{n_T n_C}{n_t + n_C}$

I'm right?