# Variance of Cohen's $d$ for within subjects designs

Tags: repeated-measures, meta-analysis, effect-size, cohens-d

Based on [this paper](http://journal.frontiersin.org/article/10.3389/fpsyg.2013.00863/full) by Lakens 2013, I understand there are two recommended ways for calculating Cohen's $d$ for within subjects measures.

1. Cohen's $d_{rm}$ (which assumes the correlation between measures is known) and can be calculated as:
   $$
   \text{Cohen's }d_{rm}=( M_{diff}/\sqrt{(SD_1^2+SD_2^2-2*r*SD_1*SD_2})*\sqrt{2(1-r)}
   $$
   Where $M_{diff}$ is the difference in means, $SD_1$ and $SD_2$ are the standard deviations of these means and $r$ is the correlation between measures.

   the variance of Cohen's $d_{rm}$ can be calculated using the following:
   $$
    V(d_{rm})=(1/n+d_{rm}^2/2n)2(1-r)
   $$
   where $n$ is the sample size. Again this assumes the correlation is known.
2. Cohen's $d_{av}$ (which ignores any correlation between measures and used the average of the standard deviations).
   $$
    \text{Cohen's }d_{av}=M_{diff}/((SD_1+SD_2)/2)
   $$
   My question is how to calculate the variance of Cohen's $d_{av}$ $(V(d_{av}))$?

Can it be calculate in a similar manner to the calculation for  independent groups - simply by substituting $d$ for $d_{av}$?
$$
V(d_{av}) = (n_1+n_2/n_1*n_2)+(d_{av}^2/2(n_1+n_2))
$$
if so some elements of this equation appear unclear as the sample size is the same for both observations.

*Calculating variance of Cohen's d for repeated measures designs?* - [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Calculating_variance_of_Cohens_d_for_repeated_measures_designs) (accessed Jan 13, 2017).

Comment: I have made some more edits subsequent to Gung's major formatting effort. Can you check the equations carefully as I am still not sure they are all correct.

Comment: Thank-you for editing these equations ! This is my first post on here so I am still unsure how to properly format !! These equations look to be correct now - thank-you!

Comment: Yes, once you ignore the correlations, you can just plug-in the estimator of Cohen's $\delta$. BTW, see [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144084/variance-of-cohens-d-statistic?rq=1) slightly different formula for its variance.

Comment: @V.V thanks for your response! Does it not matter that n1 and n2 are the same sample (as this is within subjects)?

Comment: It makes the formula slightly more elegant, nothing more. It is equivalent to a so-called "balanced design" Cohen's $\delta$. Anyway, it seems like the main issue should be the omitting of the autocorrelation that you have to be concerned about.

Comment: Actually, that is not true. The derivation given [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/185377/1934) is for two independent samples, but the question here is about a within-subjects design.

Comment: @Wolfgang your `metafor` package implements the change score standardization (`SMCC`) and references it by `Gibbons et al., 1993`. I had a look in this paper but I couldn't find whether Gibbons, and thus your SMCC implementation, applies the correction factor `sqrt(2 (1-r))` or not - would be grateful if you could clarify!

Comment: `SMCC` is for the standardized mean difference using change score standardization, so $d = M_{diff} / SD_{diff}$. `SMCR` is for raw score standardization, so $d = M_{diff} / SD_1$.

Comment: @Wolfgang thanks a lot. sorry to ask again, but does `metafor::escalc(measure="SMCC")` calculate  by `sqrt (SD21+22−2××12)` as you specified in your answer below? If yes, why without the correction `sqrt(2 (1-r))`? Is that negligible?

Comment: Yes to your first question. Because this is change score standardization to your second question.

Comment: @Wolfgang thanks a lot for the clarification! Now I can describe your function correctly. Lastly, I'm curious about your opinion - do you think one can neglect this correction factor √2(1−) which the Lakens 2013 paper cites by reference of Cohen (1988)??

Answer (score 9):

There is no know derivation of the variance of $d_{av}$. In fact, this is not how one should compute the $d$ value for a within-subjects design (neither with $d_{rm}$ or the $d_{av}$).

There are two approaches for computing a $d$ value for a within-subjects design. The first uses *change score standardization* and is given by $$d_c = \frac{M_d}{SD_d},$$ where $M_d$ is the mean change and $SD_d$ is the SD of the change scores (which is equal to $SD_d = \sqrt{SD_1^2 + SD_2^2 - 2 \times r \times SD_1SD_2}$). The large-sample variance of $d_c$ is $$Var[d_c] = \frac{1}{n} + \frac{d_c^2}{2 \times n}.$$

The second approach uses *raw score standardization*. Here, we standardize based on the SD of either the pre- or the post-test scores (typically, the SD of the pre-test scores is used). So, we compute $$d_r = \frac{M_d}{SD_1}.$$ The large-sample variance of $d_r$ is $$Var[d_r] = \frac{2(1-r)}{n} + \frac{d_r^2}{2 \times n}.$$

We do not take the average of $SD_1$ and $SD_2$ in the second approach (and if anything, we would compute $\sqrt{(SD_1^2 + SD_2^2)/2}$ but again we also do not do that). If you would do this, then it becomes nearly impossible to derive the variance, because $SD_1^2 + SD_2^2$ does not follow a (scaled) $\chi^2$ distribution, since the pre- and post-test scores are not independent. If you look at the answer given [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/185377/1934) (which is about the independent samples case), you will see that the derivation of the variance involves the non-central t-distribution, which is also involved in deriving the two variance equations above. However, to get that non-central t, you need (the square-root of) a (scaled) $\chi^2$ distribution in the denominator.

Comment: My reason for choosing dav is that it does not require knowledge of r. The problem with drm, dc and dr, is that knowledge of r  is required. I am conducting a meta-analysis in which r is not typically reported for each study. I can either try to estimate r based on the scores available in the literature, or use dav - which does not require r. My aim was to compute both and perform a sensitivity analysis to observe the differences, however I cannot do this without knowing how to calculate variance for dav- are you suggesting that this is not possible? Thanks for your help

Comment: Again, I do not know of any derivation of the variance of $d_{av}$, and I don't think there is. But it would involve $r$, just like the variance for $d_r$. So, there is no way around knowing or 'guestimating' the correlation here, regardless of what kind of d value you compute.

Comment: [There are at least 5 different ways in actual practice that people compute a d statistic for a within-subjects design](http://jakewestfall.org/blog/index.php/2016/03/25/five-different-cohens-d-statistics-for-within-subject-designs/). Curious for any comments you have on that (which you could leave here or at my blog, whichever is more appropriate).

Comment: @JakeWestfall This was too long for a comment here, so I commented at your blog.

Comment: Dear Wolfang, $(1)$ could you please provide a reference for the large-sample variance of $d_c$? $(2)$ is the variance of bias-corrected $d_c$ (Hedge's *g*) the following: $Var(d_c) \times (Hedge's~ correction factor)^2$

Comment: (1) Gibbons, R. D., Hedeker, D. R., & Davis, J. M. (1993). Estimation of effect size from a series of experiments involving paired comparisons. Journal of Educational Statistics, 18(3), 271-279. (2) Yes and no. In principle, yes, but the equation for $\mbox{Var}(d_c)$ is a large-sample approximation to begin with. So, it is debatable whether one should apply the same correction factor to the variance. In fact, based on https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.3102/1076998606298034 the answer might be that one should not.

Comment: Yes, that equation is the bias correction factor. It applies to various effect size measures. For a SMD of two independent samples, $df = n_1 + n_2 - 2$. For the two-dependent samples case, $df = n - 1$.

Comment: May I possibly invite you to take a look at [**this similar question**](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/406632/standard-error-for-difference-between-two-independent-gains) in this regard?

Comment: @Wolfgang (March 2021): New research should be acknowledged: The distribution of the Cohen's d in repeated measures when we take as denominator $\sqrt{SD_1^2+SD_2^2)/2}$ is now known (doi: 10.20982/tqmp.16.4.p418). It does require knowledge of the correlation.

Comment: Awesome! Will take a look when I get the chance.

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful answer @Wolfgang! Just a quick question: how to extend those two approaches to three time points?

Answer (score 4):

Structural equation modeling (SEM) is your friend in this case. We need the sample means and the covariance matrix as inputs. We may label the parameters (`m1`, `m2`, `sd1`, and `sd2`) and define $d_{av}$=`(m2-m1)/((sd1+sd2)/2)`. SEM automatically calculates $Var(d_{av})$ by taken the correlation between the pre- and post-test scores into account.

The followings are the `R` code using the `lavaan` package. You may refer to Chapter 3 in Cheung (2015) for the details.

```
library("lavaan")

## Sample covariance matrix on pre- and post-test scores
lower <- '10
          8 12'
( Cov <- getCov(lower, diag=TRUE, names=c("x_pre","x_post")) )

## Means of the pre- and post-tests
Mean <- c(10, 13)

## Sample size
N <- 50

model1 <- '# Label the sds with sd1 and sd2
           eta_pre =~ sd1*x_pre
           eta_post =~ sd2*x_post
           # Fix the error variances at 0
           x_pre ~~ 0*x_pre
           x_post ~~ 0*x_post
           # Label the means with m1 and m2 
           x_pre ~ m1*1
           x_post ~ m2*1
           # Define d_av
           d_av := (m2-m1)/((sd1+sd2)/2)'

## Fit the model
fit1 <- cfa(model1, sample.cov=Cov, sample.mean=Mean, 
            sample.nobs=N, std.lv=TRUE, 
            sample.cov.rescale=FALSE)

## Display d_av and its SE
parameterEstimates(fit1)[12, -c(1,2,3)]

## Output
   label   est    se   z pvalue ci.lower ci.upper
12  d_av 0.905 0.131 6.9      0    0.648    1.163
```

Reference

Cheung, M. W.-L. (2015). [Meta-analysis: A structural equation modeling approach](https://courses.nus.edu.sg/course/psycwlm/internet/metaSEMbook/index.html). Chichester, West Sussex: John Wiley & Sons, Inc.

Comment: Nice approach, Mike!

Comment: Thanks. It is based on maximum likelihood estimation. Thus, it is likely biased in small samples.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Tried it out and compared it against the bias-corrected version of $d_r$ in my answer. Would be interesting to see which has lower MSE.

Comment: One option is to two correlated effect sizes between T2 and T1, and T3 and T1. Then a multivariate meta-analysis can be used to account for the dependence.