# How can I convert difference-in-differences to an effect size?

Tags: meta-analysis, difference-in-difference

I haven't been able to find a good source on a way to convert the difference in differences to Cohen's D. The way I've been calculating the DD is:

`((mean_treatment_post - mean_treatment_pre) - (mean_control_post - mean_control_pre)) / sd`

How can I convert this to a Cohen's D or Glass' Delta?

Comment: Have you tried looking at other answers on this site like https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/256053/variance-of-cohens-d-for-within-subjects-designs which seems quite fully explained?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variance of Cohen's $d$ for within subjects designs](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/256053/variance-of-cohens-d-for-within-subjects-designs)